# 1 to 1 relationship EF two foreign keys error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
    public class Picture
        { 
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public int NewsId { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("NewsId")]
            public virtual News News { get; set; }

            public int PostId { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("PostId")]
            public virtual Post Post { get; set; }        
        }

    public class News
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public virtual Picture Picture { get; set; }
        }

public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Picture Picture { get; set; }
    }
```

Exception:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types  'Project.BusinessObjects.Photo' and 
>   'Project.BusinessObjects.Student'. The principal end of
>   this  association must be explicitly configured using either the
>   relationship fluent  API or data annotations.

Whats wrong?

Comment: You have posted wrong source code, because your code example doesn't have Advantage type.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve the problem by creating new [key] data annotations above the other classes' keys. Like this:

```
public class Picture
{ 
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("News")]
    public int NewsId { get; set; }
    public virtual News News { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Post")]
    public int PostId { get; set; }        
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }        
}

public class News
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Picture Picture { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Picture Picture { get; set; }
}
```